# Zend Framework - 404 when accesing an action in a controler with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, action

in a view i'm trying to modify the content of a window with ajax

```
$.updateWindowContentWithAjax("gendocumento","<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'contratistas','controller'=>'Personal','action'=>'generarDocumento' ,'id'=> $this->personal['id']),NULL,true)?>");
```

the 'generarDocumento' action should print the id in the terminal with the 'error_log()' method

```
public function generarDocumentoAction(){
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    error_log($this->_getParam('id'));

}
```

but it doesn't do anything and in the terminal i get

```
[404]: /contratistas/Personal/generarDocumento/id/177
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard i can't see the problem, i'm kinda noob on jquery and ajax

Comment: A 404 error is a "file not found".

Comment: @JayBlanchard hahah i know, but why. The controller and action are there, even there is a method that does the same but it goes to the "addarchivo" method in the same controller.

Comment: Have you created a route for the AJAX request?